# Add column to list with mailto function that takes users from 2 columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

So I have 2 columns "Owner" and "Deputy Owner", both are User columns and both filled.

Is there some way I can make a new column, where I add a `mailto` icon and after clicking on it, a new mail opens with recipients from **both columns**?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using? Are these user columns allow multiple user selection or group selection OR just single user selection?

Comment: I use ShP online, and I can input multiple users and even groups. But in this case, I use 1 person in Owner column and 1 or 2 people in Deputy Owner column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint online modern experience, you can [use column formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting) to add `mailto` action in one of the column in your list view.

Try using below sample JSON:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "attributes": {
    "href": "='mailto:' + join([$Owner.email], ';') + ';' + join([$DeputyOwner.email], ';')"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "display": "inline-block",
        "padding": "0 4px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "Mail"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "Send email"
    }
  ]
}
```

Where `Owner` & `DeputyOwner` are internal names of your user columns. You can get the exact internal name of your SharePoint columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Output**:

[image]

---

This is just a general JSON sample for `mailto` action. You can enhance it as per your requirements by looking at the [Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Comment: Thanks. What if I have that column named "Deputy Owner", not "DeputyOwner"? Is there some syntax change?

Comment: You can find out the **internal name** of your column using this [link](https://plumsail.com/docs/help-desk-o365/v1.x/How%20To/Find%20the%20internal%20name%20of%20SharePoint%20column.html). Always use the internal name in JSON formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this functionality by following 2 ways.

1. Create Flow which will trigger on click of button. Pass current item id to flow which will get all item properties. Button can be added to any list view column by JSON column formatting.
   Refer below link to add Button on each row and trigger flow.
   https://wonderlaura.com/2018/07/18/button-in-sharepoint-list-to-trigger-microsoft-flow/
2. Create SPFx command set extension which will add custom action on context menu through that you can get current item properties and trigger mail.

Answer (score 1):

You could use below JSON code.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "padding": "12px"
      },
      "txtContent": "email"
    },
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "Mail",
        "class": "sp-field-quickActions",
        "href": {
          "operator": "+",
          "operands": [
            "mailto:",
            "=[$Owner.email] + ';'+[$DeputyOwner.email]"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Result:

[image]
[image]

========================

Update:

Go to library settings -> Columns section -> Click Deputy Owner -> Check internal name in the browser link.
[image]

Comment: What if I have a space in the column name? Deputy_x0020_Owner does not work for me and nor DeputyOwner, as you mention in your answer.

Comment: Please refer the updated answer to check internal name of Deputy Owner column.